# The type or namespace name 'entityName' does not exist in the namespace. CodeDOM and EF trouble

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, codedom

I am using Entity Framework. I am generating both my entities and contexts dynamically with CodeDOM (one context for every entity type until I get into complex entity relationships). In order to make sure the entity I generate is part of the model of its corresponding context, I am using reflection to get the entity's type and I write this into the code that generates the context. To see this more concretely, I have this method in my class that generates the context:

```
public static CodeMemberProperty HardCodeDbSet(string contextName, Type entityType)
{
    string entityName = entityType.ToString();
    CodeMemberProperty prop = new CodeMemberProperty();
    prop.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
    prop.Name = entityName + "s";
    prop.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType));
    return prop;
}
```

This methods generates the following line in the generated context class:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.GeneratedEntities.Soap> Soaps
{
}
```

It says Soap and Soaps because in my test program I made the entity name Soap (just something random). But in general it will be whatever entity name I give it.

When I try to generate an instance of this class to use, however, I get the following error:

> "c:\Users\MyUserAccount\Documents\ContextTest\bin\Debug\EFEntityTest_v1.cs(29,94) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Soap' does not exist in the namespace 'Models.GeneratedEntities' (are you missing an assembly reference?)\n"

Line 29, column 94 is exactly where Soap starts in the line after GeneratedEntities.:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.GeneratedEntities.Soap> Soaps
{
}
```

So clearly this line isn't working properly:

```
prop.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType));
```

I know it has something to do with the fact that I'm calling MakeGenericType on something that's also generated dynamically with CodeDOM, but I feel like it should work. Does anyone have any ideas of what's going on? Also I do have the reference assembly passed in for the project where Models.GeneratedEntities is.

Comment: Yes in my test program I define Soap beforehand and it gets generated on disk to ..\Models\GeneratedEntities\Soap.cs. Edit: Wait, no it doesn't lol. It goes to my \bin\Debug folder where EFEntityTest_v1.cs is too. Maybe that's why... I'll report back soon

Comment: Is that the exact output from your code? It should be something like this `public DbSet<ModelName> Soaps { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes that's the exact output. It's because CodeDOM uses full type names. I agree that if you were to hardcode the context it would be written like you have written it, but they should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: I didn't mean the names, I meant the bit in between the braces.

Comment: Ah right, well I suppose I could add `prop.HasGet = true` and `prop.HasSet = true` statements in the method.

Comment: Well at the moment, it's acting as a method, not a property so you will get a compile error as not all paths return a value.

Comment: Oh sorry I should clarify that this method is just to create the CodeMemberProperty. I later pass this CodeMemberProperty as an argument to another method that generates CodeDOM classes, so I believe it should be acting as a property.

Comment: @DavidG oh you're totally right. I got a compile error that says `...EFEntityTest_v1.Soaps.get: not all code paths return a value\n`